# How to retrieve more than one column using ExecuteScalar?

Tags: c#

I am getting one column using `ExecuteScalar`:

```
 cmd.commandtext = "select rodeuser from customer_db_map";
    string rodecustomer = cmd.executescalar;
```

But I need to get more than one column, e.g.:

```
 cmd.commandtext = "select rodeuser,username,password from customer_db_map";
```

I need each column in a string:

```
 string rodecustomer = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 string username= cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 string password = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

But that is not possible. How is this achieved?

Comment: That's not what `ExecuteScalar()` is for. Use `ExecuteReader()` and read them off a data reader.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

To achieve this you need to use `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` Method

Comment: If you want to give the underlying provider the opportunity to optimize the query for a single row, the ExecuteReader method can use the CommandBehaviour.SingleRow parameter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

ExecuteScalar returns first columns of first row ,so you can use a trick like this

```
var m = cmd.commandtext =    select str(rodeuser)+','+username+','+password  from 
    (select rodeuser,username,password from customer_db_map)

string[] result=m.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
string rodeuser=result[0];

string username=result[1];

string password=result[2];
```

Comment: If you need more than one result, you should use the ExecureReader method as Prakash Kalakoti has written in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get several values with an `ExecuteScalar` command. You would want to use an [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc093a69.aspx) command instead.

Here is an example:

- [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx)

Alternatively you can use [`DataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx):

- [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx)