# Return multiple values from sql to label

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the label:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl1.Text = ImageCheck().ToString();
}
```

And:

```
protected int ImageCheck()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\***.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
    string CommandText2 = "SELECT * FROM Machreta WHERE noImage = 1";
    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(CommandText2, connection);
    connection.Open();
    int check = (int)command2.ExecuteScalar();
    connection.Close();

    return check;
}
```

How can i return multiple values? That label display only single value but there are 6 more in the table.

Comment: `command2.ExecuteReader()` and gether info in the reader.

Comment: I think at first you need to read some basic articles how to work with c# and sql server...[article from quick search](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx)

Comment: What do you want to display? `ExecuteScalar`'s description explicitly states that it returns the first column of the first row of the result set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate more than one column using executescalar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291716/how-to-populate-more-than-one-column-using-executescalar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
    protected string ImageCheck()
    {

      var result = new StringBuilder();

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\***.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"))
    {
        string CommandText2 = "SELECT * FROM Machreta WHERE noImage = 1";
        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(CommandText2, connection);
        connection.Open();

      using(var reader = command2.ExecuteReader())
      {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
          result.Append(reader.GetString(0));
        }
      }

      return result.ToString();

    }
 }
```

of course is **only** an example and not fully solving your issue but should be a starting point :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the explanation of ExecuteScalar() method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

"Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Extra columns or rows are ignored."

Also, SELECT * will fetch all the columns. You probably want to display multiple values for single column. Then select the column name in select statement.

```
SELECT xyzColumn FROM Machreta WHERE noImage = 1
```

Lastly, you can assign only one string to label.text. So, you will have to concatenate all these strings (multiple values for single column) and then assign it to label text. Use a reader and ExecuteReader() method instead of ExuecuteScalar().