# Retrieving value from sql ExecuteScalar()

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have the following:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Temp WHERE Temp.collection  = '" + Program.collection + "'";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
Program.defaultCollection = (String)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

And I want to get the second column after executing the statement. I know it will return only one row with two columns

I have read online that I will have to read each row of the result, is there any other way?

Comment: So do you want just the second column, or both the first and the second? If you just want the second column, you should use an explicit column list and put the column you want first.

Comment: I can just filter the selection to only return that column, then executescalar, good idea?

Comment: It's bad practice to be using `SELECT *` in the first place. You should use explicit column lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate more than one column using executescalar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291716/how-to-populate-more-than-one-column-using-executescalar)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` gets the first column from the first row of the result set. If you need access to more than that you'll need to take a different approach. Like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapater sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
sda.Fill(dt);

Program.defaultCollection = dt.Rows[0]["defaultCollection"];
```

Now, I realize that the field name may not be `defaultCollection`, but you can fill that in.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) for `ExecuteScalar`:

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

Now, as a final bit of advice, please wrap all ADO.NET objects in a `using` statement. Like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   sda.Fill(dt);

   // do something with `dt`
}
```

this will ensure they are properly disposed.

Comment: makes perfect sense!!

Answer (score 2):

> And I want to get the second column after executing the statement

It is not possible with execute scalar.

> is there any other way

You have 2 options here either to use SqlDataAdapter or SqlDataReader. 
`For you using DataReader is a recommended` approach as you don't need offline data or do other worh

**by using SqlDataAdapter**

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(
    youconnectionstring))
    {
    c.Open();
    /
    using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, c))
    {

        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        a.Fill(t);
        if(t.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
             string text  = t.Rows[0]["yourColumn"].ToString();
         }    
    }
    }
```

**by using DataREader**

```
 using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //read data here
            string text = reader.GetString(1) 
        }


        reader.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` can be used **only** when the result have just **one** row and **one** column.

If you need more than one column to be returned, you should use something like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Temp WHERE Temp.collection  = '" + Program.collection + "'";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if(rdr.Read()) 
        {
            Program.defaultCollection = (String)rdr["Column1"];
            Program.someOtherVar = (String)rdr["Column2"];
        }
    }
    rdr.Close();
}
```

That will be the fastest way.

Comment: As others have stated ExecuteScalar can be used against queries that return more than one column and more than one row or returns null.  It may not be ideal to use in some cases because the underlying query may have multiple joins and fields and various conditions that could result in a more involved query plan.  It is better suited for counts or ids.  

I have used it to preload data i.e., do execute scalar on one request then request the data via ExecuteReader later on when I think a user needs it so it seems faster (with mixed results).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DataReader and read only the first column like:

```
IDataReader cReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if(cReader.Read())
{
    string cText = cReader.GetString(1); // Second Column
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar only returns one value. You have to make sure your query only returns that value.

```
String sql = "SELECT temp.defaultCollection FROM Temp WHERE Temp.collection  = '" + Program.collection + "'";
```

On a side note, read on [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx). You don't want to concatenate values like that, you'll have a problem when the collection property contains a quote.