# SQL execution query output to show in a messagebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows application which executes some sql queries in a database. If we connect to a database and execute manually, we will be getting some message from sql server management studio(SSMS) either it may be success or failure. I want that message to be printed in my application message box. I googled and tried some code like:

```
string test = ((string)SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
MessageBox.Show(test);
```

But the result which is printed here is something else, which is not expected. I confirmed by executing the same step manually which shown me success message.

Can anyone please help me on this? Any comments would be really appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is wrap the execution in a [try catch block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and display the message if an exception occurs, otherwise, success.

Something like

```
try
{
    SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    MessageBox.Show("Success");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("An exception occurred : {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

The [Exception class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) might be a bit generic, so you might wat to refine the catch block with multiple catches to manipulate the error message.

Comment: I want to print the message which we get while doing manually..Here in this case I am not recieving that message.

Comment: Sorry to be offtopic but I love the 'MessageBob' thing you have going there. Sounds like a great name for a messaging library.

Comment: @Moeri fixed it sorry. Could be something like the Assistant in the old MS Word?

Comment: @vysakh which message are you looking for?

Comment: @astander: Suppose if we execute manually, let us assume we are getting user login created message in sql management studio. I want the same message to be printed in my messagebox also.That is my application should read whatever message from sql database and display it.

Comment: But that is a message from SSMS, not the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not needed to use ExecuteScalar then I would suggest that you use one of the methods as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211964/retrieving-value-from-sql-executescalar)

Comment: how can i do that?any idea on this?

Comment: Do you need to use ExecuteScalar? If not rather use one of the solutions as discussed in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211964/retrieving-value-from-sql-executescalar

Comment: I would also suggest that you have a look at Entity framework and wrapping your database code in using statements.