# Switch Statement Issue when authenticating user and directing them to the proper menu

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, authentication, switch-statement

```
        private void btnSubmitt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;"))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())

        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE [TX_EMPLOYEE] = @userName";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", Environment.UserName);
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())

                if (reader.HasRows.Count == 1)
                {
                        switch (reader.HasRows[0]["CD_EMP_TYPE"] as string)
                        {
                            case "0":
                                {
                                    Window1 AdminMenu = new Window1();
                                    AdminMenu.Show();
                                    this.Close();
                                    break;
                                }
                            case "1":
                                {
                                    MainWindow AnalystMenu = new MainWindow();
                                    AnalystMenu.Show();
                                    this.Close();
                                    break;
                                }
                            default:
                                {
                                    label1.Content = "SSO authentication unsuccessful. Please contact your database administrator";
                                    break;
                                }

                        }

                }

        }

    }
```

I am trying to implement a Single Sign-On and I am getting an error on (reader.HasRows.Count == 1) and (reader.HasRows[0]["CD_EMP_TYPE"] as string)
I've used (Row) as well and it did not work.

Comment: Why are you calling `ExecuteScalar`? And how many rows does your query actually return? Maybe you should try with `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Users] WHERE [TX_EMPLOYEE] = @userName`?

Comment: From doing some research it was suggested to use it. I tried using TOP 1 and removing ExecuteScaler but it didn't work. And I am looking at one column to return information from a single cell  @mm8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving value from sql ExecuteScalar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211964/retrieving-value-from-sql-executescalar)

Comment: @SMor Thank you, this helps me understand when it's appropriate to use Execute Scaler. However, I am still struggling with my solution.

Comment: You struggle because you misuse the functions. The WHOLE point of using that function is to simplify the code you need to write to retrieve a single (scalar) value. Use executereader to traverse the rows and columns. Either change the function you use or change your query - they need to match logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.8):

> An `SqlDataReader` provides a way of reading a *forward-only* stream of rows from a SQL Server database.

This means that you cannot determine the number of rows returned by your query using a reader.

But you don't need to. You could simply read the next row by calling the `Read()` method:

```
private void btnSubmitt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;"))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 CD_EMP_TYPE FROM [Users] WHERE [TX_EMPLOYEE] = @userName";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", Environment.UserName);
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            reader.Read();
            int CD_EMP_TYPE = reader.GetInt32(0);
            switch (CD_EMP_TYPE)
            {
                case 0:
                    {
                        Window1 AdminMenu = new Window1();
                        AdminMenu.Show();
                        this.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                case 1:
                    {
                        MainWindow AnalystMenu = new MainWindow();
                        AnalystMenu.Show();
                        this.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        label1.Content = "SSO authentication unsuccessful. Please contact your database administrator";
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If your query may return several rows, you should call `Read()` in loop. See the docs link above for an example.

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting an "cannot convert from string to int" error on string CD_EMP_TYPE = reader.GetString("CD_EMP_TYPE"); More specifically on ("CD_EMP_TYPE")

Comment: @IanMark: This means that `CD_EMP_TYPE` is an `int `column in the database and that you should handle it as such. See my edit.

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting the same error and now I'm getting an error with case (0 & 1) which states "cannot implicitly convert type string to int". I tried using GetInt64 and 16 and that didn't work.

Comment: On which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: On ("CD_EMP_TYPE"); and now on (case "0") and (case "1")

Comment: Did you see that I replaced "0" with `0`? Are you getting a compilation or runtime error?

Comment: I did not. Now I'm just getting the same exception with ("CD_EMP_TYPE"); which states "cannot convert from string to int"

Comment: @IanMark: Again: On what line? And during compilation or runtime?

Comment: Line 46 during compilation

Comment: What makes you think anyone but you knows what "line 46" is? A hint: Try to just copy my code sample and run it as-is...

Comment: I also checked my Data Type in SQL Server and the CD_EMP_TYPE column is listed as Int

Comment: It's line 12 and yes I did.

Comment: @IanMark: Do you still think I can see your line numbers...? Where am I suppose to see them?

Comment: My bad. This is the line....  int CD_EMP_TYPE = reader.GetInt32("CD_EMP_TYPE");

Comment: Now I get an Invalid Cast Exception. "Method name expected"

Comment: @IanMark: Where?

Comment: Line: int CD_EMP_TYPE = reader.GetInt32(0)("CD_EMP_TYPE"); and the exception is "reader.GetInt32(0)

Comment: @IanMark: Look at my edited answer and copy it once again...there is no "CD_EMP_TYPE" there.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for being patient. I'm sure you can tell I'm new to coding. But thanks again.

Comment: @IanMark: You're welcome. Please ask a new question if you have another issue.